# I am trying to update a new column with a value if at all there is an empty value in another column in my dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update column `Report['Failure Reason']` with value `"Interface Failure"` if column `Report['BSD']` is empty. Report is my dataframe.

i tried with the below code, it throws

> "SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression" error

```
Report['Failure Reason'] = np.where(Report['BSD'] = '', 'Interface Failure', ' ')
```

if `Report['BSD']` is empty, column `Report['Failure Reason']` should be updated with value `"Interface Failure"`, else it should be ignored

Comment: `np.where(Report['BSD'] == '', 'Interface Failure', ' ')` , you missed out the `==` instead you were putting a single `=` which is assigning not comparing

Comment: Hi anky_91! yes, thank you! i missed the ==. I tried again, it still does not happen, i have no clue why.

Comment: probably they are not empty strings and NaNs intead, check the below answer by @jezrael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is empty string use `==` only:

```
Report['Failure Reason'] = np.where(Report['BSD'] == '', 'Interface Failure', ' ')
```

Or if there is missing value test it by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
Report['Failure Reason'] = np.where(Report['BSD'].isna(), 'Interface Failure', ' ')
```